# A view materialized in Cassandra 3.11.8 does not show the same number of rows as the base table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have the following table in Cassandra 3.11.8

```
create table MyTable (
    id int, 
    farm_id int, 
    etc...., 
    primary key (farm_id, id)
);
```

After inserting the table with data (14,273,683 rows):

```
select count (*) 
from MyTable 
where farm_id = 1504;
```

### count

20964

Note: there is no row in the table (MyTable) with ID null.

After I created a materialized view as follows:

```
create materialized view MyView 
as 
  select id, farm_id 
  from MyTable 
  where farm_id = 1504 
  and id is not null 
  primary key (id, farm_id);
```

But when checking the number of rows inside the view I got the following result:

```
select count(*) from MyView;
```

### count

10297

I tried many times and the result is the same.

What is happening?

Comment: materialized views  are still experimental, so you either hit the edge case, or it still building - check the view status with `nodetool viewbuildstatus`: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/viewbuildstatus.html

Comment: root@cassandra-0:/# nodetool viewbuildstatus test.MyView





test.MyView has not finished building; node status is below

Very strange, because I created the view a many hours ago

Comment: I’m not very familiar with Cassandra version of the code, so it could be bottleneck somewhere... you can increase number of MV building threads

Comment: Where I increase that MV thread number?

Comment: There is a nodetool subcommand - don’t remember exact name out of head

Comment: root@cassandra-0:/# nodetool rebuild test.MyView


nodetool: Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (3547253963576016396,3596402067393954158] in keyspace system_distributed

Comment: That’s wrong command. That’s for rebuilding of tables

Answer (score 0):

Only difference is **id is not null** being added in the where clause of view. Maybe you can check how many rows are there with id=null for given farm_id in the original table.

Comment: components of the primary key (`farm_id` & `id`) couldn't be null by definition

Comment: None of the rows have ID with the value null, besides that I imported all the data from a table (Postgres) and in this table the ID column is the PK

Comment: I believe that the materialized view for Apache Cassandra 3.11.8 is still immature and needs to be more consistent. Perhaps version 4.0 will improve this. For now I will not use them in production